# How to set notification channel and deviceUdid for Quickblox push notification in react native

Tags: react-native, quickblox

const subscription = { deviceToken: global.deviceToken }

```
        QB.subscriptions
            .create(subscription)
            .then((response) => { /* subscription(s) created successfully */

                console.log('in subscription',response)
            })
            .catch(e => { /* handle error */

                showError(
                    'Error occured while subscribing to push events',
                    e.message
                )
            })
```

Comment: Hope this article helps: https://docs.quickblox.com/reference/push-notifications#events

Note that a push notification event has a field "notification_channel.name" that represents the notification channel name. Possible values are: apns, apns_voip, gcm, and email.

Answer (score 0):

To create a subsription for push notifications for specific channel, try the following:

```
QB.subscriptions.create({
    deviceToken: "your deviceUDID",
    pushChannel: QB.subscriptions.PUSH_CHANNEL.APNS
  })
```

Note that this will limit you from receiving push notifications from other channels.

To send a push notification to a specific channel, use the following approach:

```
QB.events.create({
    notificationType: QB.events.NOTIFICATION_TYPE.PUSH,
    pushType: QB.events.PUSH_TYPE.APNS,
    payload: {
      message: 'Your push message text'
    }
```

Also, check [this article](https://docs.quickblox.com/reference/push-notifications#section-universal-push-notifications) to see how a universal push notification can be sent. Universal push notifications will be delivered to all possible devices/platforms for specified users. To send Universal push notifications just omit `event.push_type` parameter within a Create Event request.